# Thread safe static property

Tags: static, thread-safety

We are also experiencing a high cpu peaks on our production server.

After researching I've found out that we have some static dictionaries in our solution..

One of them looks like this:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, List<ID>> OrderNrLookupTable
    {
        get
        {
            const string cacheKey = "ProductRepository_OrderNrHashTable1";
            var results = CacheManager.GetFromCache<Dictionary<string, List<ID>>>(cacheKey);
            if (results == null)
            {
                results = new Dictionary<string, List<ID>>();
                foreach (var orderNrItem in GetAllOrderNrs())
                {
                    var product = orderNrItem.InnerItem.Parent;
                    if (product != null && product.IsProduct())
                    {
                        if (!results.ContainsKey(orderNrItem.OrderNumber))
                        {
                            results.Add(orderNrItem.OrderNumber, new List<ID> {product.ID});
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            results[orderNrItem.OrderNumber].Add(product.ID);
                        }

                    }
                }
                CacheManager.SaveToCache(results, cacheKey);
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
```

My question is; Is this thread safe? Could this cause the high cpu peaks on our production servers?

**Update**
The threads are not modifying the dictionary.

Comment: It is impossible to tell with the given snippet whether this code causes high cpu usage. You will have to profile that code on a test server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that's impossible to tell, but could this cause issues when multiple threads try to access this static property?

Comment: It all hinges on whether your CacheManager is thread-safe. I don't think that is part of the standard library, so I cannot tell whether it is.